# How to embed HTML so external CSS does not affect it?

Tags: html, email

I am creating a page where people can preview html. The problem is, I don't want the page's external CSS to affect the HTML output. So far, I'm thinking:

1) Include it in an IFrame, and make sure the page being included is the pure html output without css --> prefer not to do this as iframes are generally a bad idea, and also, this route is a bit tricky with Drupal.
2) Include "Reset css" for a tag and pop the html in that tag

The HTML being previewed is a preview of an e-mail. I.e. The result will be sent via e-mail and therefore needs to be as accurate a depiction of what the end e-mail will look like as possible. I know this is very tricky, as all email clients produce output differently. But nevertheless, I am trying to get as close to a realistic representation as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using an IFrame is appropriate in this case. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) uses IFrames for their previews.